# Как разместить grid элементы по центру?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Как разместить grid элементы по центру?

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 280px));
 grid-column-gap: 18px;
 grid-row-gap: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.children {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно что бы черные квадраты стали по центру, либо что бы между ними стали одинаковые отступы, как это сделать?

Comment: как и при display: flex - используем justify-content: center.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`justify-content: center;` Странно, правда? )

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 280px));
  grid-column-gap: 18px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.children {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня не работало это свойство по какой-то непонятной причине

Answer (score 3):

У меня тоже не работало, а вот это заработало

```
justify-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравиться больше вот так:

```
height: 100vh;
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

или так:

```
height: 100vh;  
display: grid;
place-content: center;
```

Можно задавать два значение, выравнивая по горизонтали или вертикали!

А для отступов подойдёт:

```
gap: 10px;
```